# In Python when utilizing a dictionary, how do you return the keys with same values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python and a beginner and I am struggling with learning a concept for the dictionary class in python. I have a dictionary that maps names of students with a test score. I need to find a way to return any instance of students having the same test score. So far I have something like this but I have been unable to proceed further.

```
def student_scores():
scores={'Shawn':95, 'Craig':74, 'William':96, 'Sara':84, 'Adam':91 'Harold':74, 'Nelson': 87}
```

I looked in my class textbook for examples and found nothing that can help me solve this problem.

Comment: In your code, there is no user with same score

Comment: @ThatBird Craig, Harold

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
scores={'Shawn':95, 'Craig':74, 'William':96, 'Sara':84, 'Adam':91, 'Harold':74, 'Nelson': 87}
dd = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in scores.items():
    dd[value].append(key)
for k,v in dd.items():
    print k,':',v
```

It gives this as output

```
96 : ['William']
74 : ['Harold', 'Craig']
84 : ['Sara']
87 : ['Nelson']
91 : ['Adam']
95 : ['Shawn']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` module from Python:

```
from collections import Counter

scores={'Shawn':95,
        'Craig':74,
        'William':96,
        'Sara':84,
        'Adam':91,
        'Harold':74,
        'Nelson': 87}

c = Counter(scores.values())
out = [{k:v} for k,v in scores.items() if c[v] > 1]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[{'Harold': 74}, {'Craig': 74}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you just want to group them by their score, and you can do it as following:

```
In [124]:the_same_scores = {} 
     ...:for k, v in scores.items():
     ...:     if v in the_same_scores:
     ...:         the_same_scores[v].append(k)
     ...:     else:
     ...:         the_same_scores[v] = [k]
     ...:         

In [125]: 

In [125]: the_same_scores
Out[125]: 
{74: ['Harold', 'Craig'],
 84: ['Sara'],
 87: ['Nelson'],
 91: ['Adam'],
 95: ['Shawn'],
 96: ['William']}

In [126]:
```

and you may just care about those persons who have the same score, and you can do it like :

```
In [127]: care_about = [i for i in the_same_scores.values() if len(i) > 1]

In [128]: care_about
Out[128]: [['Harold', 'Craig']]
```

And also you want to know how many score their got the same, and you can do it by :

```
In [133]: care_about = {k: v for k, v in the_same_scores.items() if len(v) > 1}

In [134]: care_about
Out[134]: {74: ['Harold', 'Craig']}
```

Comment: What is 'the_same_scores'?

Comment: @quamrana Sorry, When paste the code I do miss it .

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Defaultdict is also a good way to do that. but I guess the pure Python may be more clear to the newbie

Comment: @FrankAK `defaultdict` IS pure python (I mean: is part of the stdlib and is what any pythoneer would use here).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers But if you want to know how it work, you have to dig into the source .

Comment: @FrankAK nope you just have to read the doc and try a couple things in the python shell - just like for anything else actually. Did you read the source to learn how `dict` work ?

Answer (score 0):

```
scores = {'Shawn': 95, 'Craig': 74, 'William': 96, 'Sara': 84, 'Adam': 91, 'Harold': 96, 'Nelson': 74}
names = []
marks = []
for key, value in scores.items():
    names.append(key)
    marks.append(value)


start = 0
for l in range(start, len(marks)):
    for b in range(l):
        if marks[l] == marks[b]:
            print('names: {} , {}'.format(names[l], names[b]))
            print('marks: {} '.format(marks[l]))
```

This will give the following output,I changed the dictionary for testing

```
names: Harold , William
marks: 96 
names: Nelson , Craig
marks: 74
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you post an answer, explain what you did. Don't just post the code